# Set test automation environment in Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have setup my Selenium WebDriver test automation suite up in Jenkins. (Maven Job)
At the moment I control the test environment (URL) through the code.

Now I need to run the same test automation suite against different environments through Jenkins.

Is it possible to control which test environment (URL) gets picked up by the tests through Jenkins?

Maybe through MAVEN_OPTS?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pass URL as environment variable. [Manual](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, pass the variable as environment variable in jenkins and access it in your code using "System.getProperty(variableName)"

```
      System.getProperty("testenv");
```

and in Maven pom.xml under surefire plugin in build tag mention the name of your environment variable within  tag.

```
       <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <testenv>${testenv}</testenv>
       </systemPropertyVariables>
```

Comment: Hi, can I store testenv url in pom.xml and refer to it? I would like to name the testenvs like dev, uat etc., and using that name in the param list not the full URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In maven command line, you can pass the environment URL as given below

```
mvn test -Dbaseurl=http://URL
```

And in code, you can get it like,

```
String url=System.get property("baseurl");
driver.get(url);
```